# Jquery mobile page navigation corrupts base url and causes ajax on main page to fail

Tags: jquery-mobile

My main page is here:
http://www.mydomain.com/main/main.php

My login page is here:
http://www.mydomain.com/main/pages/login.php

Main.php uses ajax to fetch data in response to a tap event.  This works fine until I navigate to my login page and then back to my main page.  After going to the login page and back, the relative paths get messed up such that the ajax looks for server file in the wrong place.

here is the ajax:

```
   1. function get_more_data() {
   2.    more_data_index += 15;
   3.    var formData = "index=" + more_data_index;
   4.     $.ajax({
   5.       type: "POST",
   6.       url: "genxml.php", // file located here:  http://www.mydomain.com/main/genxml.php
   7.       cache: false,
   8.       data: formData,
   9.       dataType: "xml",
  10.       success: showFiles3,
  11.       error: onErrorMoreData
  12.     });
  13. }
```

After I navigate back to main.php from login.php the ajax tries posting to the wrong location:
http://www.mydomain.com/main/pages/genxml.php

(genxml.php is not in the "pages" subdirectory; it's in the main directory.)

I tried updating the ajax to use an absolute path:
url: "http://www.mydomain.com/main/genxml.php"

This made the post successful, but my data parsing failed because relatives paths are used in the main file for things like images.  So instead of getting images from here: http://www.mydomain.com/main/ the script was trying to get images from here: http://www.mydomain.com/main/pages/

I've found a few posts with people having similar issues, but I've not come across a solution.  I've also tried reading the jquerymobile docs and it's very possible that the jquery developers attempt to cover this issue here, but I admit I don't completely understand everything on this page:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/#/demos/1.0b3/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

P.S. This issue happens on Android and Google Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: I ended up using absolute addresses for all of my ajax queries and img src attributes.  This was a real pain.  I'd really like to know how to use relative paths successfully within the jquery mobile framework.

If anyone else does this I recommend using a javascript variable so you only need to edit the path in one place.  i.e.:
var base path = "http://www.mydomain.com/main/";

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem.  Watching the DOM in Chrome's Developer Tools window while I click an ajax-enabled link, I see the <base> url change from http://example.com/ to http://example.com/Program, which is right, but then it changes right back to http://example.com/.  Subsequent navigation fails.  This must be a common problem, and I'm surprised there's not a fix.  Like you I'm not sure I understand the navigation web page you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a working example of what you're trying to do.  You should be able to look at this and see what I've done.  Be sure to checkout the master.js.  I think that the key to making it work in your situation is to nest the ajax calls within the "pageshow" event to be sure that your baseURL has been updated.  You can download the example at http://www.roughlybrilliant.com/stackoverflow/7372909.7z

[View the example](http://roughlybrilliant.com/stackoverflow/7372909/index.php) in action as it pulls in weather.xml with relative URLs.

```
$("div").live("pageshow", function(){
    var $page = $(this);
    get_more_data();
});
```

Comment: You've created two separate pages, including JQM on each page. JQM has an ajax system that allows you to pull HTML from a file containing just the page content. This base url problem occurs in the latter case.

Comment: True, however, it is a best practice to code every page with the jquery mobile code because with the URL rewriting now present in the library, the URL displayed in the address bar will reflect only the page just loaded (if your system supports it). This keeps the URLs clean and better able to be bookmarked.  So, if the user refreshes the page, it will load only the latest page. Not the base page followed by the ajaxed page as you seem to be intending.

Comment: Keeping the jquery mobile on every intended mobile page also ensures that no matter what the user's entry point, they will get the right experience. Also, this allows for true progressive enhancement because each page can stand alone so on systems with only class B, C, and lower support can still view your content. 

Does that clarify things a bit more?

Comment: The inclusion of the jquery mobile code on each page has no ill effect and the pages after the first will still be loaded by Ajax. Including the library on each page does not stop Ajax loading of that page or any other. Just makes it more bullet-proof.

Comment: Moreover, that's not why this solution works. I delay the loading of the Ajax until the page show ever has fired which fixes what I believe was a timing issue for you to begin with.

Comment: If this still doesn't solve the issue or serve as an example of how else to solve it, perhaps I could be pointed to the actual code experiencing the issue. Happy to help but all I've had to go off was the description.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I believe the issue is that the base dir is changing on every call to changePage, whereas a normal base directory does not dynamically change. I will award you the bounty since your post has been most helpful and this issue is probably caused by the way JQM works, or it may be a bug.

Comment: You are correct.  The base URL is changed with every call to reflect the URL of the currently loaded page.  Otherwise, relative image, script, and ajax calls would not function properly.  This is quite intentional.  Not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of this:

1. use "../main.php" when redirecting back from login page, or
2. remember UrlRefer from Headers when you entering login.php and use that to redirect back to any previous page with 301

Comment: Because, when redirecting programatically you cannot know what the current base dir is, at it keeps changing on every changePage call.